# BigQuery - field not found error in query fixed by removing window function

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query which fails with error:

```
Error: Field 'p.Amount' not found.
Job ID: 507322187707:job_fVoYoa96dRCgUM3omhHZNkPfgmg
```

Query works find If I remove the field, but it also works find if I remove the following line for the query (job 507322187707:job_bvFsbFdR67t_Gb3o7bLi4Wo25Kw):
lag(Hit_Date) over (partition by C,B,Status order by Hit_Date) prevDate

The query also works if I remove the alias from the erroneous field.
This might have to do with the fact erroneous query contains 2 windows functions, each with a different partition (great new feature!).

Why does the error appear and why is it fixed by removing the window function which doesn't mention the problematic field.